# How can I check the working (on/off) “wifi” adapter in objective-c or swift?

Tags: ios, wifi

Please tell me, how can I know if a "wifi" adapter working at the moment in objective-c or swift?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question. What it is exactly that you want to know?

Comment: @rmaddy, How can I check the operation (ON / OFF) "WiFi" adapter on objective-c or swift?

Comment: Repeating your question's title is not clarifying your question.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok, why did you delete my tags?

Comment: Because the tags aren't relevant to the question.

Comment: You can check using this link : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849755/how-to-check-if-wifi-is-on-or-off-in-ios-swift-2/45815818#45815818](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849755/how-to-check-if-wifi-is-on-or-off-in-ios-swift-2/45815818#45815818)

Answer (score 5):

The Reachablity sample is a good place to start. Within the Reachablity sample the code is spread out and doesn't show you how to handle the simplest case. For the simplest case (not listening to changes in state) I can save you the effort of having to collate the right lines yourself.

Copy the Reachability class from the Reachablity sample into your project, include it in your class, and use the following code:

```
if ([[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] currentReachabilityStatus] != ReachableViaWiFi) {
    //Code to execute if WiFi is not enabled
}
```

Find Reachability here :

> https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: It will not help me, because I can not be connected to the network "wifi" then "Reachability" say that I am connected to "3g" or other, I need to check if the "wifi" on/off.

Comment: My application can not stable work if "wifi" adapter off

Comment: @Zarochintsev so you can check using this code in your appDelegate.