# Multipeer Connectivity wifi & bluetooth off

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

Is there any way in iOS to detect if Wifi & Bluetooth is off so that I can show alert to the user to enable it from settings.

**Note:** I am interested in the hardware setting is on/off not the internet is reachable or not.

Comment: Please check this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849755/how-to-check-if-wifi-is-on-or-off-in-ios-swift-2

Answer (score 0):

//For Wifi
Use SwiftReachability https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

//declare this property where it won't go out of scope relative to your listener

```
 let reachability = try! Reachability()

//declare this inside of viewWillAppear

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reachabilityChanged(note:)), name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
    do{
      try reachability.startNotifier()
    }catch{
      print("could not start reachability notifier")
    }

  @objc func reachabilityChanged(note: Notification) {
   let reachability = note.object as! Reachability
     switch reachability.connection {
  case .wifi:
      print("Reachable via WiFi")
  case .cellular:
      print("Reachable via Cellular")
  case .unavailable:
    print("Network not reachable")
  }
}
```

stopping notifications

```
reachability.stopNotifier()
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .reachabilityChanged, object: reachability)
```

// For bluetooth 
     import CoreBluetooth

```
 var myBTManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
```

//BT Manager

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager)
{

    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
   // myBTManager!.startAdvertising(_broadcastBeaconDict)
    } else if peripheral.state == .poweredOff {
   // myBTManager!.stopAdvertising()
    } else if peripheral.state == .unsupported
    {
    } else if peripheral.state == .unauthorized
      {
      }
 }
```

Comment: `println(__FUNCTION__)` Are you really still coding in Swift 1.x? or too much copy paste?

Comment: @LeoDabus my aim is to help someone - giving ideas how it works. just not more than this. but for you i edit it

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for network connection availability

```
func isInternetAvailable() -> Bool {
var isNetworkReachable = false
if let reachability: Reachability = try? Reachability() {
    isNetworkReachable = reachability.connection != .unavailable
}
return isNetworkReachable
```

}

for BLE

```
class BLEManager: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

var bleManagerDelegate: BLEManagerDelegate?
var bluetoothManager: CBCentralManager?

private override init() {
        super.init()
    bleManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue:nil,
                                        options:[CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: true])
}

//CBCentralManagerDelegate method invoked
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        var bleStateError: BLEError  = .kBLEStateUnknown
            switch central.state {
         case .poweredOff:
         // powered Off
         case .poweredOn:
         // powered On
             case .unknown:
             //
         case .resetting:
             //
         case .unsupported:
         //
             case .unauthorized:
             //
    }
}
```

}